# Objective C delegate method

Tags: objective-c

a quick question. When design a delegate, if there is any optional delegate method, should I always use the following code to check if the delegate conforms the method?

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(changeBackgroundColor:number:)]) {
    [self.delegate changeBackgroundColor:self number:aNumber];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always do that, yes. Especially when you have optional delegate methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended since you're risking to invoke a nonexisting selector.

Comment: _Very strongly_ recommended, since actually invoking a nonexistent selector will generally cause the app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your delegate like:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <YourDelegateProtocol> delegate;
```

and your YourDelegateProtocol has no optional methods, there is no need to check for responding selector. In case when your delegate's class hasn't implement all of YourDelegateProtocol methods, compiler will show error. You should make check for responding selector only for optional methods of the protocol.